# JS deleting object behind reference instead of deleting reference

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to delete/replace object behind a variable reference instead of deleting/changing the reference of the local object? e.g.:

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ManuelFink/5neLbocd/

```js
var global_used_objects = {"a":"1","b":"2"};

function TheInstance() {
    var local_used_objects = global_used_objects; 
    this.resetUsedObjects = function() {
        // simulating komplex nesting with same variable name used before;
        var global_used_objects = {}; // global reference lost
  
        // remove all used objects globaly
        local_used_objects = {}; // only resets local scope and removes reference
        global_used_objects = {}; // only resets local scope and removes reference

        // This changes reference of local_used_object from global_used_object to {}. 
        // However I'd like to remove all objects from global_used_objects.
        // in reason of multi-nesting global-used_objects is not accessible here!
    }
    this.getUsedObjects = function() {
        return local_used_objects;
    }
}
var theinstance = new TheInstance();
console.log("local",theinstance.getUsedObjects(), "gobal", global_used_objects);
console.log("reset",theinstance.resetUsedObjects());
console.log("local",theinstance.getUsedObjects(), "gobal", global_used_objects);
```

I'm working in an complex object oriented prototyping js app with nested singeltons, thus I cannot simply access the parent element!

Comment: In your example, `local_used_objects` is pointing to a locally scoped version of `global_used_objects` due to [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Comment: @JamesThorpen— *local_used_objects* is assigned **the value** of (local) *global_used_objects* at the point that the assignment is made, which is *undefined*.

Comment: @RobG Well, yeah - my phrasing could have been better.